# Making App Aware of Authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

I have a c# Application where I call a `user control` with a `click event`. This `user control` provides the **authentication** to a **MySQL** database.

I dont want them to be able to use any of the other controls if they did not authenticate.

How can I make the rest of the Application aware that this user is authenticated. Can I somehow set a property in the main window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `bind` the `IsEnabled` (or similar) properties of the controls to an `IsAuthenticated` Property of the Window / ViewModel. This would be the simplest because then you don't have to manually set the properties and just set the `IsAuthenticated` value to true / false.

The other option would be to manually set all of the IsEnabled to true / false depending on if authentication worked.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a separate logon page and not allow them access to the application Page / Window at all until there is a successful logon.   In the constructor of the other pages just block them if the user is not authenticated.   I have not used MemebershipServices in WPF but in ASP.NET it is clean with page level authority based on authenticated and even by Role.   You can use  App.cs for your global variables / properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can put everything that should not be accessible inside of an invisible Panel and disable it. This will also disable all children.